# How would I monitor I/O on multiple circuits at the same time?

Tags: circuit-analysis, multimeter

I've got a device that communicates over a 8 wire cable. I'd like to examine the signals going into and out of the device without having to test each line individually with my multimeter. Is there a device better suited for this task?

I was imagining some kind of multi-channel multimeter that could monitor more than one circuit at a time, but even then I'm not sure I need that much detail (though if an affordable one existed < $150 I might consider it). Even a simple array of LEDs that lit when a given wire was active would almost be enough. Ideally something in between these two examples would be best.

Short of building something myself, is there some off-the-shelf tool/device that could serve this purpose?

Comment: Are the lines purely digital or mixed analog?

Comment: An older PC that has a parallel printer port (mostly superceded by USB now but you can buy a USB - IEEE1284 adapter) can read, display and even log to a file all 8 wires, as well as decode them if they carry ASCII data bytes. Tutorial here: http://www.logix4u.net/parallel-port/parallel-port/15-a-tutorial-on-parallel-port-interfacing

Comment: It is easier to configure the parallel port for EPP or ECP (fastest, allows DMA) on Win95/98 operating systems and trickier for 98/2000/NT/XP though this reference provides a solution: http://www.logix4u.net/parallel-port/16-inpout32dll-for-windows-982000ntxp. Warning: the above advice assumes that your cable carries digital signals which never swing outside the 0 to 5V range of the *powered* printer port connections; the PC can be damaged if an externally powered device drives the printer port when the PC power is off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want a Logic Analyzer. There are many available quite cheaply, such as the Saleae Logic (and illegitimate clones thereof).

Comment: Wow, the Saleae Logic looks like it's exactly what I was looking for, perhaps better than what I thought I could find at that price!

Answer (score 3):

Use eight comparators -- you can get 4/package using two [LM339](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm339-n.pdf)'s -- and run the reference voltage (whatever you consider the level for a lead to be "active") to the + lead of each comparator.  The reference can be provided by a resistor divider, as shown in the schematic below (resistors R2 and R3).

Run each of the leads in your cable to the - leads of each comparator.  Connect the outputs to the cathode end of 8 LED's.  The anodes should be connected to +5 via resistors (shown as R1 in the schematic) chosen to limit the current to 6 mA (which is the minimum the LM339 can sink).

The reason for connecting the comparator "upside down" (reference to +, input to -) is so the comparator will ground the output (turn on the LED) when the input is > reference.

This scheme works whether the signals are analog or digital, as long as the reference voltage is chosen appropriately.

[image]

All eight channels can probably be built for two or three dollars.